# How to update keycloak helm chart version through values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm trying to upgrade keycloak helm chart in Azure Kubernetes by passing image tag values to new version, but it is only picking old version value from chart.yaml.

I am using this keycloak helm chart repository.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak

my Chart.yaml

```
apiVersion: v2
name: keycloak
description: A Helm chart to deploy Keycloak and Keycloak Config CLI
appVersion: 22.0.5
dependencies:
- name: common
  repository: oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts
  tags:
  - bitnami-common
  version: 2.x.x
keywords:
- keycloak
version: 17.3.6
```

values.yaml

```
keycloak:
  image:
    repository: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak
    tag: 23.0.6-debian-11-r4
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Add any Keycloak specific configurations here

keycloakConfigCli:
  image:
    repository: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak-config-cli
    tag: 5.9.0-debian-11-r1
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Add any Keycloak Config CLI specific configurations here
```

Comment: you can update the tag value under keycloak.image in the values.yaml file to the desired version. For example, if you want to update to version 24.0.0-debian-11-r0, you can change the tag value to 24.0.0-debian-11-r0. After updating the values.yaml file, you can run the Helm upgrade command with the new version specified in the values.yaml file.

Comment: yes, I tried that but helm upgrade is only taking old value of appVersion from chart.yaml

Comment: can you try - helm upgrade --reuse-values -f values.yaml {release-name} {release-path} --version {fixed-version}
`example`- helm upgrade --reuse-values -f prometheus/values.yaml prometheus-operator stable/prometheus-operator --version 5.7.0 --namespace monitoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same keycloak [link](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/keycloak) which you used and was able to # [update keycloak helm chart version through values.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77987279/how-to-update-keycloak-helm-chart-version-through-values-yaml)

First deploy keycloak as usual using your link

[image]

Once deployed, now in order to change the version
first, identify the Keycloak Helm release: `helm list -A`
then verify if your keycloak is deployed as stateful or not using `kubectl get statefulsets -A`
This command will list all StatefulSets across all namespaces. Look for Keycloak in the output. Now that you know that your Keycloak deployment is deployed as a StatefulSet, not a Deployment.

update the Keycloak image in a StatefulSet, use the following command:

```
kubectl set image statefulset/keycloak keycloak=docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:23.0.6-debian-11-r4 -n default
```

This command specifies the image for the `keycloak` container within the `keycloak` StatefulSet in the `default` namespace.

You can verify the progress using

```
kubectl rollout status statefulset/keycloak -n default
```

Finally after rollout is complete verify

```
kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=keycloak -n default -o=jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"
```

There you go-
originally when initially deployed, it was at 23.0.7

[image]

now it is at 23.0.6 debian-11-r4
[image]

pods are up as well
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to trigger the changes you made in the values.yaml file you will need to change the Chart version in Chart.yaml file as well, then run the helm upgrade command for your keycloak helm chart